# Installed mysql via brew but terminal can't find it. What's the proper way to alias it on a macos?

Tags: mysql, bash, macos, homebrew

MacOS 10.12.6

Installed mysql via brew

mysql files are in /usr/local/Cellar/mysql\@5.7/5.7.24/bin

What is the proper way to make these available from the command line and from bash?

Thank you!

Comment: which macos ? here is an article for sierra - https://gist.github.com/nrollr/3f57fc15ded7dddddcc4e82fe137b58e

Comment: 10.12.6 Sierra sonyes ill try your suggestion

Comment: This is what I did but MySQL has not been aliased or added to bash path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution to your problem is given using the command:

```
brew info mysql@5.7
```

which states:

```
If you need to have mysql@5.7 first in your PATH run:
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Thank you. I was running `brew info mysql` which did not provide this info. Unfortunately, even after this, CraftCMS installed on my dev machine cannot find mysqldump to export the database. Any ideas?

Comment: This is a different problem. Ask a new question and describe in details what you tried and which results you obtain.

Comment: thank you. almost all answers make path /usr/local/var/mysql which is not existing on my machine, i just realize that mysql via homebrew make another path for mysql

Comment: Finally an answer that solved my problem. Thank you!